# Images won't display in IE9

Tags: image, internet-explorer-9

When I open my website on IE9 the images simply dissappear. It works fine with IE7, IE8, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.
What is the problem?
The images are declared as:

```
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/image1.jpg" alt="alternative text">
```

Thanks in advance! :S

Comment: Works fine in my IE9. Make sure you are running the RTM, not an RC or a Beta.

Comment: Which images specifically? Did you look in the F12 Network tab or Fiddler to see if there are any networking failures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Kaspersky or other antivirus software programs installed, they sometimes block images from loading in IE but not chrome.

For example, the anti-banner protection in Kaspersky today kept a few of my website images from loading.  I added it to the exclusion list and they popped right up.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers everybody, in the end all was working properly. The only problem was that I was testing the website via the software IETester, and for some reasons the simulation it did not display the images. Later on I upgraded to IE 9 and all images display correctly.

Comment: If the question is answered - accept your own answer. This will mark your question as closed.